# Return a specific variable of a JSON body in REQUEST nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, httprequest

I have this code which works perfectly well for me, it brings me the body in JSON, but I don't want the whole body, I want a specific variable of that same body, this is the code.

```js
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://xxx',
  qs: {stats: 'true', events: 'true'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'xx',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'xxx'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 if (error) throw new Error(error);

 console.log(body);
    **console.log('HOME NOMBRE: ' + body.results.id);**
});
```

this gives me a JSON file like this:

```js
{"results":[{"id":1,
"idSeason":949,
"seasonName":"2020",
"idHome":2069,
"homeName":"MyHome",
"idAway":207 ....}
```

I would like to be able to realize some method that brings me exclusively the variable, for example, homeName, to be able to work only with it!

I hope I am explaining well, I expect your help!

Comment: So to clarify, the API returns an array of objects, and you'd like an array with just one property, like, for "homeName", you'd want ["MyHome", "SomeOtherHome", etc]?  That's just what map or underscore pluck() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better way to do this is just use ES6 map.

if you use array of objects

```
const results = [{
  "id": 1,
  "idSeason": 949,
  "seasonName": "2020",
  "idHome": 2069,
  "homeName": "MyHome",
  "idAway": 207
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "idSeason": "x",
  "seasonName": "x",
  "idHome": "x",
  "homeName": "MyHomex",
  "idAway": "x"
}]

const formattedRes = results.map(singleObject =>{
// Here redeclare the object you want, here i want to return id,seasonName and homeName
  return {
       "id": singleObject.id,
       "seasonName": singleObject.seasonName,
       "homeName": singleObject.seasonName,
        }
});
console.log(formattedRes);
```

result will be

```
[ { id: 1, seasonName: '2020', homeName: '2020' },
  { id: 2, seasonName: 'x', homeName: 'x' } ]
```

for more [map - MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Its pefect for me!

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936472/publish-a-twit-on-twitter-api-with-specific-functions-from-another-js-file

Answer (score 0):

If your API returns an array of objects, and you just want an array of values for one of the objects' properties, use map...

```js
let results = [{
  "id": 1,
  "idSeason": 949,
  "seasonName": "2020",
  "idHome": 2069,
  "homeName": "MyHome",
  "idAway": 207
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "idSeason": 950,
  "seasonName": "2021",
  "idHome": 2070,
  "homeName": "MyHome2",
  "idAway": 208
}]

// native
console.log(results.map(e => e.homeName))

// or using underscore
console.log(_.pluck(results, 'homeName'))

// or a smaller object
console.log(results.map(e => _.pick(e, 'id', 'seasonName', 'idAway')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```