# How to publish a tweet using Twitter API with specific functions from another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, twitter, unirest

This is my bot.js file... it consists of a simple twit publishing function with node.js

```js
 const config = require('./config')
 const datasport = require('./botele')
 const twit = require('twit')
 const T = new twit(config)


 T.post(
    'statuses/update',
    { status: ' : '+ datasport.formattedRes },
   
    (err, data, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("oof! Something went wrong!");
        } else {
             console.log("Tweet sent successfully!");
    
        }
      } 
  )
```

Then, in my botele.js file I have to..

```js
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "xxx");

req.query({
 "stats": "true",
 "events": "true"
});

req.headers({
 "x-x-host": "x",
 "x-x-key": "x"
});


req.end(function (res) {
 if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);


 const formattedRes = res.body.results.map(singleObject =>{
  
    return {
      "homeName": singleObject.homeName,
    }
  });
  
  module.exports = {
   "formattedRes": formattedRes
  }
 


});
```

formattedRes returns exactly the variable I want: homeName like this:

```
homeName: MyhomeName
```

What I want is for my MyHomeName variable to appear on Twitter when I publish the twit!
so I can work with it as:

```
{ status: ' :This is my home name call: '+ datasport.formattedRes + 'And yours? :) ' },
```

clearly gives me this on twitter post:

> This is my home name call: undefined And yours? :)

some help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `module.exports` is inside a function. That is not the way you export something.
What you should do is export the function which generates `formattedRes` then run it to get your required data, and then use that data.